# Error publishing to Sonatype because "repositoryUrl" is null

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, sonatype

I've been trying to publish a project to Sonatype's repository, but I got an error and I can't find the solution online.

I have the following `publishing` block on my `build.gradle.kts` file:

```kotlin
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("mavenJava") {
            pom {
                name.set("Keen")
                description.set("A genetic algorithm framework for Kotlin")
                url.set("https://github.com/r8vnhill/keen")
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name.set("Attribution 4.0 International (CC BY 4.0)")
                        url.set("https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode")
                    }
                }
            }
            groupId = "cl.ravenhill"
            artifactId = "keen"
            version = projectVersion
            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "sonatype"
            if (version.toString().endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) {
                maven("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
                    name = "ossrh"
                    credentials(PasswordCredentials::class)
                }
            } else {
                maven("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
                    name = "ossrh"
                    credentials(PasswordCredentials::class)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the error I've got:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJavaPublicationToSonatypeRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'sonatype'
   > Cannot invoke "java.net.URI.getScheme()" because "repositoryUrl" is null
```

Any idea of what could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository called 'sonatype' doesn't have a URL.

Assuming the version is a snapshot version, e.g. `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`, what you've written is

```kotlin
repositories { 
  maven {
    name = "sonatype"
    
    maven("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") { 
      name = "ossrh"
      credentials(PasswordCredentials::class)
    } 
  }
}
```

This is also equivalent to

```kotlin
repositories { 
  maven {
    name = "sonatype"
  }
  maven("https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") { 
    name = "ossrh"
    credentials(PasswordCredentials::class)
  } 
}
```

So repository 'sonatype' has a name, but doesn't have a URL.

Gradle will create a publication task for each defined repository, even if the definition isn't valid (which can't be known ahead of time). If you ran the Gradle task

```bash
./gradlew publishMavenJavaPublicationToOssrhRepository
```

it would succeed.

To correct the problem, remove the 'sonatype' repository. It would also be more clear if you defined the target URL in a separate variable.

```kotlin
val ossrhRepositoryUrl = if (version.toString().endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) {
  "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
} else {
  "https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
}

publishing {
  repositories {
    maven(ossrhRepositoryUrl) {
      name = "ossrh"
      credentials(PasswordCredentials::class)
    }
  }
}
```